# Program crash after wxThreadEvent::GetPayload()

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I have a C++ program in Code::Block with gcc and wxWidgets. 
After my working thread throws a `wxThreadEvent` with a struct as payload my program crashes (actually not at the throw, but at the moment I want to get the payload in the main).

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

The working thread part:

```
wxThread::ExitCode NavigationThread::Entry()
{
  wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_REFRESH_DIRECTION);
  position_variables positionPayload;
  positionPayload.latitude = latDouble;
  positionPayload.longitude = lonDouble; 
  positionPayload.direction = direction;
  event.SetPayload(&positionPayload);
  m_parent->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(event);
}
```

The struct:

```
struct position_variables{

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    wxString direction;
};

class NavigationThread : public wxThread
{
  ...
}
```

The main.cpp

```
WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
     Bind(wxEVT_THREAD, &WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onRefreshDirections, this, ID_REFRESH_DIRECTION);
}

void WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onRefreshDirections(wxThreadEvent& event)
{
    position_variables answerDirections = event.GetPayload<position_variables>(); //Here it crashes
}
```

When the crash occurs in normal "run" mode, a windows opens saying the program stopped working. In debug mode there is a small window in Code::blocks saying something about `SIGSEGV, segmentation fault` (or something like that) and this is the Call Stack:

```
#0 00877A54 std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) () (??:??)
#1 04A1E550 ?? () (??:??)
#2 007ED139 position_variables::position_variables(this=0x4a1e588) (D:/WindowsDgps/WindowsDgpsGUI/NavigationThread.h:54)
#3 00851B54 wxAny::As<position_variables>(this=0x4c6fe70) (C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2/include/wx/any.h:979)
#4 0084E70C wxEventAnyPayloadMixin::GetPayload<position_variables>(this=0x4c6fe58) (C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2/include/wx/event.h:1219)
#5 0043320E WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onRefreshDirections(this=0x4be2a68, event=...) (D:\WindowsDgps\WindowsDgpsGUI\WindowsDgpsGUIMain.cpp:440)
#6 0063AA48 wxAppConsoleBase::HandleEvent (this=0x4b2bde0, handler=0x4be2a68, func=(void (wxEvtHandler::*)(wxEvtHandler * const, wxEvent &) (../../src/common/appbase.cpp:611)
#7 0063AAD9 wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(this=0x4b2bde0, handler=0x4be2a68, functor=..., event=...) (../../src/common/appbase.cpp:623)
#8 0062DEA1 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(entry=..., handler=0x4be2a68, event=...) (../../src/common/event.cpp:1392)
#9 0062EB3A wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(this=0x4be2a68, event=...) (../../src/common/event.cpp:1751)
#10 0062E318    wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(this=0x4be2a68, event=...) (../../src/common/event.cpp:1585)
#11 007C50A0    wxEvtHandler::TryBeforeAndHere(this=0x4be2a68, event=...) (../../include/wx/event.h:3671)
#12 0062E157    wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(this=0x4be2a68, event=...) (../../src/common/event.cpp:1522)
#13 0062E0FF    wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(this=0x4be2a68, event=...) (../../src/common/event.cpp:1495)
#14 0062DCEC    wxEvtHandler::ProcessPendingEvents(this=0x4be2a68) (../../src/common/event.cpp:1359)
#15 0063A69C    wxAppConsoleBase::ProcessPendingEvents(this=0x4b2bde0) (../../src/common/appbase.cpp:520)
#16 007F0883    wxIdleWakeUpModule::MsgHookProc(nCode=0, wParam=1, lParam=77720172) (../../src/msw/window.cpp:7454)
#17 746BE1A1    USER32!TrackMouseEvent() (C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\user32.dll:??)
#18 ??  ?? () (??:??)
```

with #2 highlighted red.

Maybe it has something to do with the `Clone()` part in [`SetPayload()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_thread_event.html#a4b9b438e229a0f53c97e6058cfc67959)? Though I don't quite get how I should use it or why my accessing of the payload would be problematic...

Comment: @AHue, do you use static event table or bind()/connect()? Can you show this code and the backtrace at the time of crash?

Comment: @Igor I edited the question with the requested parts. I found a workaround though, now I use two events each of wich gets a `SetString` with the necessary information, but I am not that happy with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a pointer to a local variable, which will be destroyed as soon as you exit the function containing it, thus making the pointer invalid, as the payload. Use the *object* itself, not a pointer to it, instead.

Comment: Dumb question but how do I do that?... I don't see where I used a pointer in the wrong place...

Comment: You use `&positionPayload`, i.e. take a pointer to the object and then store it as the payload. It's the _pointer_ that it getting copied by `wxThreadEvent` instead of the object itself.